# Calling java-code from oracle-db

Tags: java, svn, oracle11g

Scenario :

The java-code(jdk1.6) was compiled using the oracle-jvm and deployed into Oracle database (11g) - (ODB).
There is already a svn-trunk (say T1) deployed in Oracle database (ODB).

Imagine the hierarchy - 
`Project1 -> src -> a -> b -> Filename1 -> method1`

I have created a seperate svn-trunk (say T2) and deployed it into the same (ODB).
 Similar hierachy was created in T2 
`Project2 -> src -> a -> c -> Filename2 -> method2`

T1 was developed and deployed by Company X and I work for its competitor company Y and therefore, I have no access to T1.
T1 was developed and deployed a few years back and now my company won the contract from Company X.Company X has blocked access to 
all code, svn etc. PL-SQL code (wrapped) calls the deployed java-code.

After loading my java files (from T2) - I was able to load the files on the oracle-database , 
that is - the files were visible in the Oracle - Java folder.

However, the code in Filename2.method2 does not get executed - I get customException saying - unable to located the file.

Questions :

1. Please correct me if I am wrong - but I think it is not possible to have 2 SVN-trunks deployed for the same application on the same environment !
2. I think the Filename2 cannot be located because ".project" & ".classpath" file of T1 does not contain any reference to Filename2
3. Is it possible to somehow extract the ".project" & ".classpath" file of T1 from the database - so that I can then modify them to point to my files?

Comment: OT: are you use abut versions? I'd bet that 11g has JVM 1.5 build in.